# Store string lists in separate columns of a listview (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, list, listview

Hope I can do this, I'm still newish to C#...

I have a bunch of lists of strings that I want to put into different columns of a Listview.  I'm able to get the first column to populate using the code shown below, but can't figure out how to do this for the subsequent columns.

```
        List<string> l_Time = new List<string>();

        //l_Time is populated by a method

        foreach (string elem in l_Time)
        {
            listViewEvents.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(elem));
        }
```

listViewEvents is my ListView

Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

Both shown solutions work to store my lists across a row, which I was able to find a lot online. I want to be able to store each list down it's own column. Is this possible?

Comment: Which UI framework? WinForms? WPF? ASP.NET?

Comment: @Joe, Good question! I was assuming he was referring to Winforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
listViewEvents.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(l_Time.ToArray()));
```

The `ListViewItem` class has a constructor that takes an array of strings. When that constructor is used, then the other strings will appear in the other columns.

If you want to do more with the other columns, then the list view item has a `SubItems` property that holds a collection of `ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem` objects. You can create these with whatever values you want and add them to the list view item objects.

**UPDATE**

Here's a way to display lists of strings in separate columns:

```
    private static void DisplayListInColumns(ListView listView, List<string> values, int columnIndex)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < values.Count; index++)
        {
            while (index >= listView.Items.Count)
                listView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem());
            ListViewItem listViewItem = listView.Items[index];
            while (listViewItem.SubItems.Count <= columnIndex)
                listViewItem.SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem());
            listViewItem.SubItems[columnIndex].Text = values[index];
        }
    }
```

Called like this:

```
        List<string> listOne = new List<string>() { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six" };
        List<string> listTwo = new List<string>() { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May" };
        List<string> listThree = new List<string>() { "alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "delta", "echo", "foxtrot", "golf", "hotel" };

        DisplayListInColumns(myListView, listOne, 0);
        DisplayListInColumns(myListView, listTwo, 1);
        DisplayListInColumns(myListView, listThree, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something along those lines:

```
// This assumes all lists have the sample number of items
for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
{
    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(list1[i]);
    lvi.SubItems.Add(list2[i]);
    lvi.SubItems.Add(list3[i]);
    listViewEvents.Items.Add(lvi);
}
```

Comment: Both those solutions work to store my lists across a row, which I was able to find a lot online.  I want to be able to store each list down it's own column.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible. Assuming all your lists have the same length, just go through the first list one item at a time, and for each item, add to `SubItems` the element from every *other* list with the same index. In other words, add the item at index 0 from *every list* to *one* ListView item, then the item at index 1 from *every list* to *another* ListView item, and so on.